# Fitting Shimano cassette to an old mavic wheel

Tags: shimano

I have a vintage CAAD 2 with Mavic Open CD wheels SUP, (very old) but perfect for what i need. The running gear is campanola but very high geared. I want to change it to Shimano which have a better range. My question is what free wheel hub will fit my mavic wheels for the Shimano 9 speed cassette i bought.

Comment: What hub is it built with? You may be able to find a replacement freehub body to fit Shimano cassettes.

Answer (score 2):

Campy and Shimano 9-speed cassette spacing are too different for the mismatch to work very well. Campy is 4.55mm cog-to-cog and Shimano is 4.35mm. It is true that it can be made to kinda sorta work, i.e. in the stand when things are clean and new, but it's finicky in real world conditions.

It seems like the Veloce 9 28t cassettes haven't been available for a while. Miche is making a Campy-compatible 9-speed 13-28 which is available though. Your simplest route by far, especially if the rear wheel is still good, is almost certainly to get that cassette and then if that isn't enough, switch to compact cranks in front.

The other path is get a new Shimano-compatible rear wheel, or build a new hub into your current rim if you really want, plus a Shimano 9 cassette that has individual cogs, and then conversion spacers for it that switch the spacing to Campy. These are the good way of doing this kind of hack. 9-speed ones have been available but I'm not sure if anyone is making them new anymore, but if not they can probably still be found.

You probably have a Campagnolo (as in made by Campy) hub now, and no replacement freehub will be available for it. At this point it's almost certainly the same deal if it happens to be a third-party Campy-compatible hub, although it is true that sometimes swapping freehub bodies on those with another type is technically possible.

(It sounds like you've got a wheelset with Mavic rims and someone else's hubs, as I don't believe there was ever an Open CD prefab set. This bike is also from before the days of named prefab sets. If I'm mistaken and the hubs are also Mavic, then there very well may be alternate freehubs out there for them, as Mavic road wheels have typically emphasized being fairly easy to switch.)

Answer (score 1):

You may find New Old Stock (NOS) hubs on ebay. I have some wheels built in the late 80s/ early 90' with Mavic Open CD rims and Shimano's Ultegra 600 hubs. Those rear hubs and those from the 105 or Dura-Ace series are normally 36-hole, though 32 existed. The hubs take 9-speed cassettes. There should still be enough of these around.

You could also try for some newer stuff, any hub with the right hole pattern and a Shimano-fitting take-up will work, although you'd have to adjust the width of the cassette with the correct thickness of spacers which isn't a problem. All cassettes down to 7-speed fit on modern hubs. Spacers of different thickness are widely available from bike shops.

But there's a bigger caveat if you want to mix Campagnolo shifting and Shimano cassettes. That won't work together unless your system uses friction shifting. If your system uses indexed shifting which a 9-speed probably does, the spaces between the cogs and the movement of the rear derailleur differ between Campa and Shimano and will not permit clean shifting.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Am i right that i need to respoke the wheel with the Shimano Utegra hub, or is the Shimano hub your referring to compatible with the mavic wheel centre i have?

Comment: @GavanDuffy : If the number of holes is identical, yes. I'd recommend you use new spokes and check the braking surfaces for wear.

Comment: The spacing for 9 and 10 speed Campagnolo and Shimano is very close and you can get away with just using the cassette from other system. Of course we have no idea if OP's bike is even 9-speed to begin with. And it's likely that if the cassette size is not available from Campagnolo, the derailleur isn't able to handle it anyway.

Comment: @ojs : Anyway, a purist would rather 'suffer' on the correct Campa cassette than run a Japanese cassette on a vintage Italian set-up. ;-) I'd keep the old wheel for purity's sake and display purposes and buy a second rear wheel with that Shimano cassette. It can't be that expensive, probably less than a new hub, spokes and the labour for a rebuilt.

Comment: @Carel a significant portion of cyclists are not purists. Besides, Campagnolo stuff is often durable, so 9-speed is not necessarily vintage that is kept for display purposes but actual working gear.